# view profile after click on hyperlink using view model and find()

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm new to mvc 4 and having trouble with loading profile after click on hyperlink in View.I'm using view model for combining several classes to one class. Below I h'v added View of Index.

```
<h3>Place</h3>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <div class="item1">
            <img src="data:image/png;base64,@Convert.ToBase64String(item.pic,0,item.pic.Length)" width="100" />
            <p class="name">@Html.ActionLink(item.Sp_name, "Details", new { id = item.SPID })</p>

        </div>

    }
```

once I click on hyperlink in Index View. I want to load it's profile.I'm having problem with where to add find(id) in controller. given below is my controller method for View profile.

```
public ActionResult Details(int id = 0)
    {

        List<ImageData> details = new List<ImageData>();
        var sp_details = (from s in db.service_provider
                          join p in db.pictures on s.SPID equals p.SPID
                          join c in db.cities on s.City_ID equals c.City_ID
                          where s.SPID == id
                          select new { s.Sp_name, s.Sp_location, s.Sp_rate, s.service_type, c.Cityname, p.pic });


        foreach (var item in sp_details)
        {
            ImageData SpView = new ImageData(); // ViewModel
            SpView.Sp_name = item.Sp_name;
            SpView.Sp_location = item.Sp_location;
            SpView.Cityname = item.Cityname;
            SpView.Sp_rate = item.Sp_rate;
            SpView.pic = item.pic;

            details.Add(SpView);
        }
        if (details == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(details);
    }
```

can somebody kindly help me to load profile after click on hyperlink in view.

Comment: I do not fully understand what do you want to do, can you be more specific, what find(id), where is the problem

Comment: I want to add something like to controller `var a=dbContext.service_provider.Find(id)`

Comment: So in your line `var sp_details = (from s in...` use `var sp_details = db.service_provider.Find(id)` or SingleOrDefault() insted Find() and add `using System.Linq; using System.Linq.Expression;`

Comment: Display data are not belong to one model class therefore I have used ViewModel for Display data. `ImageData` is my viewmodel

Comment: In this case you can't use default Find() you can only in your service provider create function Find() which will returns all data you need.

Comment: you have gone wrong direction..this is what I have done. I have use db first approach for my project.I have created SQL server db and created ADO.net model. In data model there are few tables namely service_provider,picture,comment.I have created viewmodel for display data in single view.I have given my controller and Index view above . After click on hyperlink in Index View I want to display view of specific profile.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
@Html.ActionLink(item.Sp_name, "Details", new { id = item.SPID },null)
```

Comment: I think that passing ID from view to controller is not a problem in his case

Comment: problem id how to select profile for specific id passed from view